# Need some advice on regex in Sigil

Tags: regex

I am having a damn pain with this regex problem, so i am making an epub file and i have a ton of refferences to link to a file at the end, which i have done, but now i need to do a returning link and i need to match the id tag numbers to the link body id numbers, i figure i could do a regex replace/find...

Referance 565

```
<p>Stuff goes here(The reference itself)</p>

<div class="back" style="text-align: justify;">
  <a href="../Text/Filename.xhtml#body_ftn2(!!! I need this to match the number of the refferance(thats how the link in text are id'd, same number just body_ftn instead of ftn))">[&nbsp;→&nbsp;Atgriezties uz piezīmes vietu tekstā&nbsp;]</a>
</div>
```

Now i figured i need to have it ignore the middle part so i did a bit of messing around in regexr and got to this,   Referance (\d+)(?s).*?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want.  the href value for `<a>` ?

if so ,you can try this:

```
(?i)(?<=<a\b[^>]*?href=(['"]?))[^'"]*?_ftn\d+[^'"]+(?=\1)
```